# Injected Serilog does log to Debug, but not File

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-6.0, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I'm trying to use Serilog with DI in my .NET 6 application. I have Serilog configured like this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.Debug()
    .WriteTo.File(@"D:\log.txt",
                  retainedFileCountLimit: 5,
                  rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();
```

and my generic Host using

`IHostBuilder host = new HostBuilder().UseSerilog(Log.Logger).Build()`

(configuration and service-addidtion not shown here for brevity).

In my service-classes I require an ILogger from the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging Package.
Now, the Problem I have is that I get correct Logging to Debug from everywhere, but the File-Sink only logs when I use Serilogs Log.Debug() Method for example.

If I comment out the "UseSerilog()" on the Hostbuilder I get no logging in Debug also. So Injection of Serilog to ILogger seems to work.

Any Ideas whats happening here ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the method's you're calling to log that are not working? Remember, it's up to you to provide us with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out it was a rather stupid mistake (for anyone interested).
Somehow I thought this was a good Idea:

```
try {
  Log.Debug("Starting Hostbuild");
  BuildHost();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Log.Fatal(ex, "Hostbuild Failed unexpectedly");
  return;
}
finally
{
  Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

Which of course reset my Serilog Logger (Log) to default after the `Hostbuild` was done in `BuildHost()`.

I think I read somewhere that you're supposed to call `CloseAndFlush` at the end, but then changed where my "end" was...

Comment: so does this code work for you or not?